# yii model->save not working for update value

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
public function actionUpdateprofile(){
    $user = User::model()->findByPk($_POST['User']['user_id']);
    $profile = Profile::model()->findByPk($_POST['User']['user_id']);

    if(isset($_POST['User']) || isset($_POST['Profile'])){
        $user->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        $profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
        $user->save();
        $profile->save();

    }
}
```

I did this code for update the value in profile and user table. But it's not working.
If i send `$_POST['Profile']['email'] = 'abc@gmail.com';`
There is no error but database still showed old value. why?

What i did wrong in there?

This is the result for `$profile->attributes`. email still have old value.

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 35
    [lastname] => asd
    [firstname] => asrtyr
    [email] => xyz.gmail.com
    [phoneno] => 123456
    [prof_img] => 
    [phoneno2] => 0
    [agentKey] => 
    [fb_id] => 
)
```

Comment: Have you added `email` to Profile model as possible column? (rules method)

Comment: What @Justinas said. If you have not defined "email" column in Profile model Rules array, it will not be saved. If you do not wish to do any validation on "email", then you still need to add it to Rules as "safe", like this:
array('email', 'safe'),

Also, you may have other validation errors which you are not seeing, because you are not checking if "save()" actually happens. It returns false when there's a validation error, then you can use $profile->getErrors() to get a list of validation errors

Comment: yes these are already done because i am using yii-user module. And it's working fine during add user. Problem only during update.

Comment: @SRana - your problem solved or not?

Comment: @coni - yes, problem solved

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to add error reporting like below

```
if(!$user->save()){
    echo 'Error to save user model<br />';
    var_dump($user->getErrors());
}
if(!$profile->save()){
    echo 'Error to save profile model<br />';
    var_dump($profile->getErrors());
}
```

Comment: Got it, that's my mistake. I forgot this line "$profile->regMode = true;" thanks all of you

Answer (score 1):

First, do this to check if it has to do with validation (look example below) and test it:

```
public function actionUpdateprofile(){
    $user = User::model()->findByPk($_POST['User']['user_id']);
    $profile = Profile::model()->findByPk($_POST['User']['user_id']);

    if(isset($_POST['User']) || isset($_POST['Profile'])){
        $user->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        $profile->attributes = $_POST['Profile'];
        $user->save(false);
        $profile->save(false);

    }
}
```

Which will bypass the validation. If it works, and you really need the validation (and you most certainly do), remove the false's I added and build it up by following the [validation guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation/). The thing to remember is: the property not associated with a rule in rules() array is considered unsafe and is **NOT** saved into the database. This might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reccommend to check possible errors on saving:

istead of

```
$user->save();
```

you could use

```
if (!$user->save()){
  print_r($user->getErrors());
}
```